Trouble calculating Drag and Lift from Ansys API
I'm following the code linked here which simulates the aerodynamics of a body, but 'm not sure how to get the final drag and lift calculations. In this code, there's a section called "Define Report Definitions" that calculates the drag force right here:
# Drag Force
session.tui.solve.report_definitions.add(
    "cd-mon1",
    "drag",
    "thread-names",
    "*ahmed*",
    "()",
    "scaled?",
    "yes",
    "force-vector",
    "1 0 0",
    "q",
)

While debugging, I've noticed that it prints what's below in the terminal.
<solver_session>.solution.report_definitions.drag["cd-mon1"] = {}
solver.solution.report_definitions.drag['cd-mon1'] = {"zones" : ["wall_ahmed_body_main", 
"wall_ahmed_body_front", "wall_ahmed_body_rear"]}

I wanted to add more to solve for (Drag coefficient, Lift force, Lift coefficient) so I added this piece of code directly under the previous one.
# Lift Force
session.tui.solve.report_definitions.add(
    "cl-mon1",
    "force",
    "thread-names",
    "*ahmed*",
    "()",
    "scaled?",
    "yes",
    "force-vector",
    "0 1 0",  # Lift force is along the y-direction
    "q",
)

# Drag Coefficient
session.tui.solve.report_definitions.add(
    "cd-coeff",
    "drag-coefficient",
    "thread-names",
    "*ahmed*",
    "()",
    "scaled?",
    "yes",
    "force-vector",
    "1 0 0",
    "q",
)

# Lift Coefficient
session.tui.solve.report_definitions.add(
    "cl-coeff",
    "lift-coefficient",
    "thread-names",
    "*ahmed*",
    "()",
    "scaled?",
    "yes",
    "force-vector",
    "0 1 0",
    "q",
)

This doesn't work. When this line is run, the program completely freezes and I have no idea why. I think it might have something to do with the solver settings, because each specific "zone" is defined from what I can tell from the terminal, but it never specifically says in the code that the cd-mon1 (drag force) is defined to "wall_ahmed_body_main", "wall_ahmed_body_front", "wall_ahmed_body_rear" (at least from what I can tell).
On top of all of this, I have no clue how to actually get the drag force calculations that's clearly defined in the code. There must be a "get_values" function or something like that, but I just can't seem to find it.
